# reference html in .js

Tags: javascript, html

Simple question.

I'm newbie on javascript and html.

I have a file index.html like:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel=StyleSheet href="beauty.css" type="text/css">
<script src="myjs.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="foo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my js file:

```
var d=new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var data = d.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear();
function showdata(){
    return data;
}

document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML=showdata();
```

I understand that I need to reference the html, but I do not have idea how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by `reference the html`? That could mean a lot of different things...

Comment: Which HTML do you want to "reference" ?

Comment: the index.html that has the first lines of code.

Comment: yes, but which part specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want

```
window.onload = function() {
   var d=new Date();
   var month = d.getMonth()+1;
   var data = d.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear();
   function showdata(){
       return data;
   }

   document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML=showdata();
}
```

You also might want to specify `type="text/javascript"` in your `<script>` tag.

Comment: One trouble with `window.onload` is that only one function can be attached this way.  If you need it for some other purpose, or you use some third-party script that does, one declaration will override all the others.  You might want to try Xavi's solution, or look at something to help you run multiple events when the DOM is ready or the window is loaded, not just a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the script tag to the bottom of the page.  Right before closing `</body>` tag.  Something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel=StyleSheet href="beauty.css" type="text/css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="foo"></p>
        <script src="myjs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that your javascript code was executed before the paragraph element was part of the page.

Comment: Why the down votes?  Moving your scripts to the bottom of the page is generally good practice regardless.  It helps improved perceived page load.  Browsers must pause page rendering every time a script tag is encountered.  By putting script tags at the bottom of the page, the browser has a chance to render all the page's content before pausing to execute javascript.  Also, `window.onload` is only executed once all the assets on the page are loaded which in many cases needlessly delays javascript execution.